# Print the Values from list in JasperReports version 3

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to get the values from the list and show it in  a tabular form. I m using sub reports. However, I am able to get the first row values from the list, i can't access the rest of the values.

I am using Ireports version 3.

Here is the Sub report:
[image]

The first row matches the Pojo fields. I need to print from second row, the other values from list.
**However, The error shows that Cant' retrieve the value from material1....**

Comment: Add some relevant jrxml

Comment: I think you have not fully understood how the detail band works... it will iterate your records, but can only verify this if you add your jrxml code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the prevoius comments, you should probably better understand how the detail band works.

The detail band iterates every "row" of your datasource, so unless you did something unconventional in your datasource, you just need a single field for every "column" in your datasource.

Basically, if your data source is something like:

```
Material   Quantity   Actual_Cost
AAA        100        5   
BBB        200        10
CCC        150        7
DDD        50         8
```

Having 3 "columns" to show, you need only 3 fields in your detail band.

Running your report, you will get 4 rows (like your datasource should suggest you).

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Fabio.

I solved my problem. It was a mistake at the java end. i didn't iterate through the list and set the values in the Hashmap. I set the values directly in the main report.  ;)